# Is it possible to generate a local, private toctree in Sphinx?

Tags: restructuredtext

I want to generate a `toctree`, within a page, that will list a certain set of pages. However, I don't want it to add that list of pages to the main `toctree` hierarchy (and therefore the sidebar).

I have a multi page documentation set with a structure like this :

```
A.rst
B.rst
C.rst
D.rst
E ---- E1.rst
       E2.rst
F ---- F1.rst
       F2.rst
```

I have an `index.rst` which includes a single master toctree directive, and E1 and F1 contain the master toctree directives for each of their folders; and all of that works fine.

The `toctrees` in `index.rst`, `E1.rst` and `F1.rst` are all marked as `hidden`, so that they don't show on the pages themselves, but they do show on the main table of contents sidebar (this is defined using the `includehidden` option).

What I want to do is to have a local `toctree` within my `B.rst` document which lists out these documents :

```
 C
 D
 F1
```

In other words a list that pulls together a set of documents which have different logical connection or common thread, separate from the primary organization of the documents. However I want this list to only appear on the B page - and not appear on the main toctree sidebar.

I know I can use a simple bullet list, but then that ignores the topics and sections that might exist in C, D etc, and also will have different classes applied for styling.

Is there a way I can build a dynamic hierarchical document list which *only* appears within, a document and doesn't get included in the main `toctree`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?